# How to build complex delete query in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a class which is an instance of Zend TableGateway and I'm trying to build following delete query (where :start, :channel and :stop are variables)

```
 DELETE FROM epg WHERE (epg_start >= '2013-11-30 11:00:00') and FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(epg_start) + epg_duration) <= '2013-12-01 01:30:00') AND epg_service = 'skytv' AND epg_channel = '4music'
```

Here is what I have tried so far

```
$where = new Where();  
$where->lessThanOrEqualTo(      
        'FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(epg_start) + epg_duration)', '2013-12-01 01:30:00'  
    )
    ->greaterThanOrEqualTo('epg_start', '2013-11-30 11:00:00')
    ->equalTo('epg_service', 'skytv')
    ->equalTo('epg_channel', '4music'); 
$this->delete($where);
```

...and I get following error

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`+` `epg_duration``)` <= '2013-12-01 00:28:10' AND `epg_start` >= '2013-12-01 00'
```

I have tried using Zend Expression class but I get error

`preg_split() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given`

Can anyone give me suggestion/example of how I can build this query using "Where" class

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you edit into your question the query that is actually run? There may be a way to get it from Doctrine, but failing that, it'll be in your database query logs. Hmm, that double-backtick looks odd - maybe `lessThanOrEqualTo` only takes columns and not expressions? Is there an alternative method that pops up in your auto-complete?

Comment: @halfer I agree lessThanOrEqualTo only takes columns and would add, alternative method to get around that is addPredicate(PredicateInterface , string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After an hour or more looking through Zend library, I finally figured it out

```
    $where = new Where();  
    $where->greaterThanOrEqualTo('epg_start', '2013-11-30 11:00:00')
        ->equalTo('epg_service', 'skytv')
        ->equalTo('epg_channel', '4music'); 
    $where->addPredicate(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression('FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(epg_start) + epg_duration) <= ?'), '2013-12-01 01:30:00');
    $this->delete($where);
```

I initial tried \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression but it should have been \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression

Comment: Great. Don't forget to tick your own answer `:)`.